# How to normalize word embeddings (word2vec)

Tags: python, nlp, normalization, word2vec, word-embedding

I have a pre trained Word2Vec model with embeddings. I need to normalize some embeddings to do analyses with the words. Is there a simple line (or block) of code to do this? I've been searching online but can't find a simple answer.

Comment: Do you mean how to make embedding vector norms the same?

Comment: what is your input? E.g. a `numpy` array or a `wv` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work fine with embeddings

```
model.init_sims(replace=True)
```

Comment: Does this normalize all the embeddings in the model?

Comment: It should replace your existing vectors with the normalized ones. Here, have a look at the documentation -  https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors.init_sims

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use `replace=True`, which destructively wipes-out the non-normed raw vectors (which are often better for some purposes). After you've used gensim's `init_sims()`, the cache of unit-normed vectors will be in the property `.vectors_norm`, and one of the other vector-access methods has a `use_norm` option to just get each individual vector as its unit-normed version.

Comment: Yes, The user can go ahead with what I've written if they have no use for the non normalized vectors. With this option, they can save some RAM which might/might not be their priority. If the original vectors might be needed in the future, I believe they can refer to your answer.